# how to know what the previous page is in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate(-1)
```

This is what I am trying to do. However, I want to know what the previous page is before going back. If the previous page is some other site, then of course, it should have no effect.

Comment: This is *at least* the third question in the last day or so asking the same thing. Don't change the default back navigation action unless you really want to annoy your users. It's generally considered poor UI/UX to "trap" users on your page/web application.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a check to verify the url origin using `window.location.origin`.

```
const currentOrigin = window.location.origin;


const navigate = useNavigate();
currentOrigin === "https://example.com" ? navigate(-1) : null
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can maintain some "state" to indicate that where it is navigated exactly from.

For Example:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate("/newPage", { state: { fromCurrentApp: true } });
```

So, from current page you can check that state and handle the navigation.

```
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const { state } = useLocation();
const navigate = useNavigate();

const { fromCurrentApp } = state || {};
if (fromCurrentApp) {
  navigate('/home', { state: { fromCurrentApp: true } });
} else {
  navigate(-1);
}
```